# google Pagespeed API error for enable MIME type

Tags: javascript

Refused to execute script from 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=https://deve…callback=runPagespeedCallbacks&key=AIzaSyDW0NYO6wh6fZ8bG5Z8TE-EQk0hLJnsNnI' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.